# Human ranked/sorted items

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I'm trying to derive an algorithm or procedure I would use to have a human interactively rank a series of items based on importance by comparing a random-pairing of items at a time.

So, given an array of let's say 10 "things", I want to present two of the things, and have the user specify which is the more important of the two.  What I don't know is:

- What is the proper name for this procedure/concept?
- Would I use some form of sorting algorithm?
- How could I determine when to stop?  When is the ranking "done"?
- And, importantly, I would prefer not to present the same "thing" to the user in a row.  That is, if comparing `Item B` and `Item K`, user selects `Item K` as more important, the next iteration should not present either `Item B` or `Item K`.

What I'm after seems similar to this question: [Nearest neighbour based on subjective human comparison - is this a thing?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75626/nearest-neighbour-based-on-subjective-human-comparison-is-this-a-thing)

... but I'm not interested in similarity, just relative importance.  Think prioritizing a to-do list or subjectively ranking vacation destinations, etc.

The [Elo Rating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) may be similar to what I'm after, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are statistical models for relative ranking.  I'd suggest taking a look at the [Bradley–Terry model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model).  The data is sometimes known as paired comparison data.

See also [Analysis and classification based on data points](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16775/755),  [Peer grading design - choosing a graph, to get accurate rankings/ratings](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18493/755), https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83005/2921.